why can't I get xml tag attributes
so I was trying to code a test for reading xml files but for some reason I can't get the tag attributes please help
python
from xml.dom.minidom import *
playerxml = parse('C:/Users/dimit/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/projects/save test.xml')
u1 = playerxml.firstChild
print(u1.firstChild.tagName)
print(u1.firstChild.tagName.getAttribute("up"))
print(u1.firstChild.tagName.getAttribute("down"))
print(u1.firstChild.tagName.getAttribute("left"))
print(u1.firstChild.tagName.getAttribute("right"))

xml
<user1>
</controls up='w' down='s' left='a' right='d'>
</name name='dimitri'>
</user1>

I tried to look at the error messages for help but I couldn't understand it mainly because it was printing out module code

Use a well-formed xml.

"I tried to look at the error messages" - If you're getting error messages, you should add them to your question.


test.xml:

<user1>
    </controls up='w' down='s' left='a' right='d'>
    </name name='dimitri'>
</user1>


main.py:

.
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

playerxml = parse('test.xml')
u1 = playerxml.firstChild
controls_tag = u1.getElementsByTagName('controls')[0]  
name_tag = u1.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]



print("Controls attributes:")
print("Up:", controls_tag.getAttribute("up"))
print("Down:", controls_tag.getAttribute("down"))
print("Left:", controls_tag.getAttribute("left"))
print("Right:", controls_tag.getAttribute("right"))

print("\nName attribute:")
print("Name:", name_tag.getAttribute("name"))

Output:
Controls attributes:
Up: w
Down: s
Left: a
Right: d

Name attribute:
Name: dimitri


sorry @TheHungryCub but that still returns the same error

@hypercoder, please make sure your xml file is well formatted. I have tried above code from my end, it is working fine.

If you use a valid xml you can do something:
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = """
<user1>
    <controls up='w' down='s' left='a' right='d'/>
    <name name='dimitri'/>
</user1>"""

dom = parseString(doc)

def att(tag):
    key = tag.attributes.keys()
    value = []
    for v in list(key):
        value.append(tag.getAttribute(v))
    return zip(key,value)

items = ['controls','name']
for tag in items:
    for elem in dom.getElementsByTagName(tag):
        for k,v in att(elem):
            print(k+' :', v)

Output:
up : w
down : s
left : a
right : d
name : dimitri

Alternative with xml.etree.ElementTree:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = """
<user1>
    <controls up='w' down='s' left='a' right='d'/>
    <name name='dimitri'/>
</user1>"""

root = ET.fromstring(doc)
for elem in root.iter():
    for k,v in elem.attrib.items():
        print(k+' :',v)

